# PHP SOAP is not buildung a correct request

Tags: php, web-services, soap

i am trying to build a specific SOAP Request in PHP with the standard SOAP-Class.

That's the Request i want to build in PHP:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.autoscout24.com/webapi/" xmlns:data="http://www.autoscout24.com/webapi/data/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:FindArticles>
         <web:request>
            <data:client_id>1234</data:client_id>
            <data:culture_id>de-DE</data:culture_id>
            <data:profile_id>CPCMS_DE</data:profile_id>
            <data:revision>3</data:revision>
            <data:vehicle_search_parameters>
               <data:address>
                  <data:countries>
                     <data:country_id>D</data:country_id>
                  </data:countries>
               </data:address>
               <data:dealer_id>2141356852</data:dealer_id>
            </data:vehicle_search_parameters>
        </web:request>
      </web:FindArticles>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried to figure out how it works:

```
        try {
        $result = $client->FindArticles(
              array(  new SoapParam((string)"de-DE", "culture_id") )
        );
    } catch (SoapFault $exc) {
        var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
```

This PHP Call echoes the following SOAP-Envelope:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.autoscout24.com/webapi/"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:FindArticles/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see, PHP ignores my SOAPParameters.
Why is that and how to fix it?

Thanks in Advance!
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used soapparam yet, I always do it this way:

```
$arrCallParams = array();
$arrCallParams['culture_id']='de-DE';
$result= $client->FindArticles($arrCallParams);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried it like that:
            $result = $client->FindArticles(array(
                "client_id" => "1234",
                "culture_id" => "de-DE",
                "profile_id" => "CPCMS_DE",
                "revision" => "3",
                "vehicle_search_parameters" => array("dealer_id" => "2141356852",
                    "address" => array("countries" => array("country_id" => "D")))
                    )
            );

But it dont works

Comment: Don't you get any meaningfull errormessages? Perhaps try var_dump($exc); in your catch routine for more info?

Comment: The Error Message is "Error: missing parameter 'culture_id'" so the Request reaches the SOAP-Server, but the Request is not complete

Comment: You can get that error both if the parameter is missing, and if the parameter is in a wrong format I noticed. So perhaps check with the provider of the soap service?